# Apple AirPods pair and connect but no sound

Tags: audio, bluetooth, iphone

## Background

I was on a call at work today and was switching back and forth from my iPhone 10 to my laptop.  After switching from laptop to iPhone my 2nd Generation AirPods stopped playing sound.  They could connect but would not play any sound.  I purchased these 3 weeks ago and they are not physically damaged.

## Trouble Shooting Steps

Here are the steps I went through to troubleshoot

1. I attempted to pair and connect with a 3rd device.  I was able to pair and connect but no sound.
2. I did a hard reset by holding the button on the back of the AirPod case for 15 seconds with the AirPods in the case.  I saw the light indicates and my iPhone had me pair the device again, still nothing
3. I disabled automatic ear detection, no change
4. I reset network services on my device.  No change

Does anyone have any idea where to go from here?

Answer (score 0):

If you did a hard reset and they don't work with either your iPhone or your laptop (multiple devices) it's safe to say that they died.

They're under a month old so I would return them for refund/replacement immediately.  Products fail - it happens.  You're just lucky enough that it happened during the "return to retailer" period (usually 30 days) and not when the warranty runs out 48 weeks from now.

Answer (score 0):

Before submitting them for repair or replacement to Apple, I would make sure you have thoroughly unpaired them from every device (laptop, phone, everything) and reset them one more time to clear any possible Bluetooth cache issues.  Then you can always seek further support from Apple.